# Transit visa via India to Australia

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, del, uzbek-citizens

Can you please tell me whether an Uzbekistan passport holder, traveling to Australia, with a 12-hour stopover in Delhi airport, India, requires a transit visa? Even if they are staying inside the airport?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa): Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours

So if your trip is in a single booking, you do **not** need a visa